# How can I make a TextArea fill the center of the screen?

Tags: java, javafx

I am using JavaFx, and I want to create a TextArea to fill the center of the screen. I am trying to a BorderPane, but no matter where in the Pane I set it (Top, Bottom, Center, etc.) it is always at the top of the screen. I also cannot get it to resize the number of cols.

```
    primaryStage.setTitle("Cauldron");
    VBox root = new VBox();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 720);
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

    MenuBar menuBar  = new MenuBar();
    Menu    menuFile = new Menu("File");
    Menu    menuEdit = new Menu("Edit");
    Menu    menuView = new Menu("View");
    Menu    menuHelp = new Menu("Help");

    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(menuFile,menuEdit,menuView,menuHelp);
    borderPane.setTop(menuBar);

    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    borderPane.setCenter(textArea);

    root.getChildren().add(borderPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

This is my code,and this is what it creates:
[image: output]

Comment: What's the purpose of the `VBox`? Why not just make the `BorderPane` the root of the scene?

Comment: I did that because I am very new JavaFX. I didn't even know a BorderPane could be the root of a scene. This actually resolved the problem. Thank You!

How do I close the question?

Comment: Any `Parent` can be the root of the scene. See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.scene.Parent,double,double)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text area is filling the center of the border pane. The issue is that the border pane is not growing beyond its computed preferred size in the `VBox`.

The `VBox` doesn't actually seem to perform any useful purpose anyway: you can simply make the border pane the root of the scene:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LayoutTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 1280, 720);

        MenuBar menuBar  = new MenuBar();
        Menu    menuFile = new Menu("File");
        Menu    menuEdit = new Menu("Edit");
        Menu    menuView = new Menu("View");
        Menu    menuHelp = new Menu("Help");

        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(menuFile,menuEdit,menuView,menuHelp);
        borderPane.setTop(menuBar);

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        borderPane.setCenter(textArea);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you really need the `VBox`, you can instruct it to always give available additional space to the `BorderPane` with

```
VBox.setVgrow(borderPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
```